# How to access postgresql by sql alchemy in airflow by using Python Operator?

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow, airflow-2.x

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago



default_args = {
    'owner': 'rudresh_mehta',
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}

def fetch_premarket_table(ti):
    # from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    # import requests
    # url = "https://www.benzinga.com/movers"
    url = "https://www.benzinga.com/premarket/"
    tables = pd.read_html(url)
    premarket_df = tables[5].to_json()
    ti.xcom_push(key="premarket_df",value=premarket_df)

def store_premarket_table(**context):
    # import packages
    import psycopg2
    ti = context["ti"]
    json_str = ti.xcom_pull(key="premarket_df", task_ids=["fetch_bezinga_premarket_table_id"])

    print("json",json_str)
    df = pd.read_json(json_str[0])
    print("df================",df)

    current_time = datetime.today()  # pytz.timezone("Toronto/America"))
    today = current_time.date()
    time_today = datetime.now().time()
    yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
    print("after today===========================")
    # establish connections
    dct = {'user': "postgres",
           'password': "root",
           'host': "127.0.0.1",
           'database': "bd_proj"}
    print("dct",dct)
    # conn_string = 'postgresql://%(user)s:%(password)s@localhost:5432/%(database)s' % dct
    conn_string = 'postgresql://postgres:root@localhost:5432/bd_proj'
    print("============",conn_string)
    db = create_engine(conn_string, pool_size=10, max_overflow=20)
    connection = db.connect()
    connection.autocommit = True
    df["date_time"] = yesterday
    # converting data to sql
    df.to_sql(name='bezinga_premarket_table', con=connection, if_exists='append', index=False)
    connection.close()
    print("Success")
    return 200


with DAG(
    dag_id='dag_with_modulev01',
    default_args=default_args,
    start_date=datetime(2022, 7, 8), #yyyy-mm-dd
    schedule_interval='8 5 * * *') as dag:

    create_premarket_tb = PostgresOperator(
        task_id='create_premarket_table_id',
        postgres_conn_id='bd_proj_postgres',
        sql="""
            create table if not exists bezinga_premarket_table(
                stock_ticker character(8),
                stock_name character varying,
                stock_price real,
                change_perc character(10),
                volume character varying,
                date_time timestamp,
                primary key(stock_ticker, date_time));
        """)
    fetching_premarket_tb = PythonOperator(task_id="fetch_bezinga_premarket_table_id",
        python_callable=fetch_premarket_table,dag=dag )
    


    store_premarket_tb = PythonOperator(
        task_id='store_premarket_table_id', provide_context=True,
        python_callable=store_premarket_table, dag=dag)

    create_premarket_tb >> fetching_premarket_tb >> store_premarket_tb
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt1p6.png)

As stated in the picture, I'm trying to solve this issue. I have tried all the available solutions over stackoverflow and other websites but nothing worked. Restarted the postgres service and even my laptop. I'm able to dump data using PostgresOperator but my third task fails after connection string is passed. Sql alchemy is the issue or something else I'm not able to figure out. I want to dump my whole dataframe at once. To simulate above code you need to run this dags. Any help is highly appreciated on this study project. thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.